# Bcrypt NodeJS - Hash de contraseña

Tags: nodejs, bcryptjs

Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de hashear la nueva contraseña de usuario, ya que devuelve null y no se como solucionarlo para que devuelva la contraseña hasheada.

```
                bcrypt.hash(newnew, null, null,(hash) => {
                    req.body.password = hash;
                    User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, params, {new: true}, (err, userUpdated) => {
                        if (err)
                            return res.status(500).send({
                                message: 'Error en la petición de actualizar la contraseña'
                            });
                        if (!userUpdated)
                            return res.status(404).send({
                                message: 'No se ha podido actualizar la contraseña'
                            });
                        return res.status(200).send({user: userUpdated,
                        hash: hash});
                    });
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estas utilizando erróneamente la función hash, según la [documentacion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) la función hash tiene dos formas de usarse (de forma asíncrona), siendo la mas practica la siguiente (puedes buscar la otra forma si quieres)

```
bcrypt.hash(contaseñaEnTextoPlano, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
    // Guardar hash en la base de datos.
});
```

***NOTA***: saltRounds debe ser un numero, mientras mas alto mas demorara en encryptar la contraseña, lo recomendado es 10.

Comment: Si lo hago como dices, tira un error node_modules\bcrypt-nodejs\bCrypt.js:621
                throw "No callback function was given."
                ^
No callback function was given.

Comment: Estas utilizando una librería obsoleta (bcrypt-nodejs) en su lugar te recomiendo utilizar bcrypt, que esta mucho mas actualizada, si quieres usar esta ultima haz lo siguiente: npm uninstall bcrypt-nodejs y luego npm install bcrypt

Comment: Muchas gracias, actualice a bcrypt y borrer bcrypt-nodejs y como me dijiste, ahora funciona todo como debe. Saludos!